# How to use the Motion class?

Tags: codenameone

I've investigated why the Codename One tensile scrolling on IOS and in the simulator is so different from the original IOS rubberband scrolling.

In order to assess this I needed to look at the `Motion` class and its various time based transitions. For that I created an app to visualize several of this `Motion`s.

Have a look:

[image]

I see several problems there. Have a look at [this example](https://cubic-bezier.com/#0,1,.2,1) for what type of motion i want to achieve - kind of a rubberband motion, fast at first but easing out like a rubberband would. I probable don't understand `com.codename1.ui.animations.Motion.createCubicBezierMotion(int, int, int, float, float, float, float)`but the values are obviously different from what I have seen elsewhere and in this example:

[image]

How would I achieve the motion in the example using CN1s `Motion` class?

Also the values over time for `Motion.createEaseInOutMotion` look too linear to be usefull.

The values over time for `Motion.createEaseInMotion` and `Motion.createEaseOutMotion` look odd or perhaps swapped.

Am I using it wrong or how am I supposed to use and understand this?

Here is the app to look into the CN1 motions:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.codename1.ui.Component;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.TextField;
import com.codename1.ui.animations.Motion;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Dimension;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Point;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.FlowLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.GridBagConstraints;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.GridBagLayout;

public class FormMotionCourse extends Form {
    private abstract class Plotter extends Component {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) {
            super.paint(aGraphics);
            aGraphics.setColor(0x000000);
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            int minExtent = Math.min(width, height);
            int size = minExtent * 90 / 100;
            int shiftX = (width - size) / 2;
            int shiftY = (height -size) / 2;
            int start = 0;
            int destination = size;
            Motion motion = getMotion(start, destination);
            motion.setStartTime(0);
            List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int xAxis = 0; xAxis < destination; xAxis++) {
                motion.setCurrentMotionTime(xAxis);
                int yAxis = motion.getValue();
                points.add(new Point(xAxis, yAxis));
            }
            for (Point point: points) {
                aGraphics.drawChar('+', getX() + shiftX + point.getX(), getY() + shiftY + point.getY());
            }
            aGraphics.setColor(0x20aa20);
            aGraphics.drawString("Time ->", minExtent - size, height - size);
        }

        protected abstract Motion getMotion(int aStart, int aDestination);

        @Override
        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }
    }

    private interface Row {
        Plotter getPlotter();
        Component getControls();
    }

    public FormMotionCourse() {
        super("FormMotionCourse");
        setLayout(BoxLayout.y());
        setScrollable(true);
        List<Row> rows = Arrays.asList(
                createCubicBezierRow(),
                new Row() {
                    @Override
                    public Plotter getPlotter() {
                        return new Plotter() {
                            @Override
                            protected Motion getMotion(int aStart, int aDestination) {
                                return Motion.createEaseInOutMotion(aDestination, aStart, aDestination);
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Component getControls() {
                        return new Label("EaseInOutMotion");
                    }
                },
                new Row() {
                    @Override
                    public Plotter getPlotter() {
                        return new Plotter() {
                            @Override
                            protected Motion getMotion(int aStart, int aDestination) {
                                return Motion.createEaseMotion(aDestination, aStart, aDestination);
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Component getControls() {
                        return new Label("EaseMotion");
                    }
                },
                new Row() {
                    @Override
                    public Plotter getPlotter() {
                        return new Plotter() {
                            @Override
                            protected Motion getMotion(int aStart, int aDestination) {
                                return Motion.createEaseInMotion(aDestination, aStart, aDestination);
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Component getControls() {
                        return new Label("EaseInMotion");
                    }
                },
                new Row() {
                    @Override
                    public Plotter getPlotter() {
                        return new Plotter() {
                            @Override
                            protected Motion getMotion(int aStart, int aDestination) {
                                return Motion.createEaseOutMotion(aDestination, aStart, aDestination);
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Component getControls() {
                        return new Label("EaseOutMotion");
                    }
                },
                new Row() {
                    @Override
                    public Plotter getPlotter() {
                        return new Plotter() {
                            @Override
                            protected Motion getMotion(int aStart, int aDestination) {
                                return Motion.createLinearMotion(aDestination, aStart, aDestination);
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Component getControls() {
                        return new Label("LinearMotion");
                    }
                },
                new Row() {
                    @Override
                    public Plotter getPlotter() {
                        return new Plotter() {
                            @Override
                            protected Motion getMotion(int aStart, int aDestination) {
                                return Motion.createSplineMotion(aDestination, aStart, aDestination);
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Component getControls() {
                        return new Label("SplineMotion");
                    }
                },
                new Row() {
                    @Override
                    public Plotter getPlotter() {
                        return new Plotter() {
                            @Override
                            protected Motion getMotion(int aStart, int aDestination) {
                                return Motion.createDecelerationMotion(aDestination, aStart, aDestination);
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Component getControls() {
                        return new Label("DecelerationMotion");
                    }
                });
        for (Row row: rows) {
            Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout()) {
                @Override
                public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) {
                    super.paint(aGraphics);
                    aGraphics.setColor(0x888888);
                    aGraphics.drawRoundRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth() - 1, getHeight(), 20, 20);
                }
            };
            container.add(BorderLayout.WEST, row.getPlotter());
            container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(row.getControls()));
            add(container);
        }
    }

    private Row createCubicBezierRow() {
        return new Row() {
            float p1 = 0, p2 = 1.75f, p3 = 0.75f, p4 = 1.0f;
            @Override
            public Plotter getPlotter() {
                return new Plotter() {
                    @Override
                    protected Motion getMotion(int aStart, int aDestination) {
                        return Motion.createCubicBezierMotion(aDestination, aStart, aDestination, p1, p2, p3, p4);
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public Component getControls() {
                Container container = new Container(new GridBagLayout());
                int y = 1;
                { // Caption
                    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                    constraints.gridwidth = 2;
                    constraints.gridy = y++;
                    container.add(constraints, new Label("CubicBezierMotion"));
                }
                { // label p1
                    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                    constraints.gridx = 1;
                    constraints.gridy = y;
                    container.add(constraints, new Label("p1:"));
                }
                { // Field p1
                    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                    constraints.gridx = 2;
                    constraints.gridy = y++;
                    TextField textField = new TextField(5);
                    textField.setText(p1 + "");
                    textField.setConstraint(TextField.DECIMAL);
                    textField.addDataChangedListener((aType, aIndex) -> {
                        try {
                            p1 = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException aNumberFormatException) {
                        }
                    });
                    container.add(constraints, textField);
                }
                { // label p2
                    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                    constraints.gridx = 1;
                    constraints.gridy = y;
                    container.add(constraints, new Label("p2:"));
                }
                { // Field p2
                    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                    constraints.gridx = 2;
                    constraints.gridy = y++;
                    TextField textField = new TextField(5);
                    textField.setText(p2 + "");
                    textField.setConstraint(TextField.DECIMAL);
                    textField.addDataChangedListener((aType, aIndex) -> {
                        try {
                            p2 = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException aNumberFormatException) {
                        }
                    });
                    container.add(constraints, textField);
                }
                { // label p3
                    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                    constraints.gridx = 1;
                    constraints.gridy = y;
                    container.add(constraints, new Label("p3:"));
                }
                { // Field p3
                    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                    constraints.gridx = 2;
                    constraints.gridy = y++;
                    TextField textField = new TextField(5);
                    textField.setText(p3 + "");
                    textField.setConstraint(TextField.DECIMAL);
                    textField.addDataChangedListener((aType, aIndex) -> {
                        try {
                            p3 = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException aNumberFormatException) {
                        }
                    });
                    container.add(constraints, textField);
                }
                { // label p4
                    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                    constraints.gridx = 1;
                    constraints.gridy = y;
                    container.add(constraints, new Label("p4:"));
                }
                { // Field p4
                    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                    constraints.gridx = 2;
                    constraints.gridy = y++;
                    TextField textField = new TextField(5);
                    textField.setText(p4 + "");
                    textField.setConstraint(TextField.DECIMAL);
                    textField.addDataChangedListener((aType, aIndex) -> {
                        try {
                            p4 = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException aNumberFormatException) {
                        }
                    });
                    container.add(constraints, textField);
                }
                return container;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: We did a similar experiment to this when they were originally authored and got graphs that were closer. This might be failing due to rounding or bugs in the algorithms. Not sure.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be much easier to use curve functions like those commonly used with javascript which translate values between zero and one? I’d also like to have a composite ˋMotionˋ composed of arbitrary other motions.

Comment: It would be nice to have motions configurable - those motions that are used by standard components

Comment: Everything is placed/translated to integer values in the end. In our case it's done in the motion class itself. You can use floating point code for the function implementation and do the rounding before returning a value which will happen anyway at some point.